# Can create enumeration as part of another enumeration?

Tags: swift, enums, enumeration

I tried to create enum, which elements will be copied of another enum, like this:

```
enum Modes {
    case mode1
    case mode2
    case additionalMode1
    case additionalMode2
}

enum GeneralModes {
    case mode1
    case mode2
}
```

I have no idea how to do this. Need some backup.
Thanks for all answers and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an `enum` inherit from another `enum` and there is no built-in way to make your `enum` implement all cases that another `enum` implemented.

One possible workaround would be to give `Modes` a case with an associated value, which will be of type `GeneralModes`.

```
enum Modes {
    case general(GeneralModes)
    case additionalMode1
    case additionalMode2
}

enum GeneralModes {
    case mode1
    case mode2
}
```

Then you can create a variable of type `Modes` with a value of `mode1` like

```
let mode1 = Modes.general(.mode1)
```